# How are games launched

Tags: games

I have downloaded programs from the Ubuntu software center,the only ones I can't find are the games. It says I have them, but I can't launch them. Where do I look for them?

Comment: This is a "brute-force" suggestion. If you know the names of the games, just open a terminal and type the name of the game, hit enter and it should lunch. If it doesn't launch then there will appear an error message. **NOTE** it must be the package name you type in, no spaces are allowed.

Answer (score 6):

type your game name in the search of unity dash and of course there is a game section which have list of all games installed in the PC . look at the image .[image]

Comment: I tried that no games found.The games are in it but can't I get to it.Games are not under filter results./

Comment: open Ubuntu Software center and you can see what are the games you have installed.

Comment: When I goto software center the green checks are on the games I have.When I click a game I have it comes up with "more info" or "remove".6 games have been installed.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you haven't used the Dash properly. I'm still getting the hang of Ubuntu myself so I can relate to your confusion.

Look again at that picture of the Dash that was posted.  Down the bottom you have a series of icons - a house, three bars (don't ask me what they're meant to be!), a page, music notes and the last one is a video icon.  Notice that in the picture, the bars are highlighted.

When you first click on the Dash icon, the house is most likely to be highlighted.  If you click the bunch of bars then you'll be shown the applications.  You'll also notice the word "Filter" appears over at the top right with an arrow.  That arrow can be used to open or close the Filter options.

Filter by clicking on the word Games (the box will be given a border to show it's selected) and then see if your game appears in that list.

If there are more games than will fit in the window, a bar appears (white in my setup but not sure if it is in the original Desktop appearance) that you can drag up and down.  Don't know if there are scroll arrows; I haven't found any. You can also navigate the window by using your arrow keys on your keyboard.

The software centre lets you see what's been installed and remove it if you want and also search for other programs to be installed but doesn't let you launch them from there.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Dash and start typing the name of the game you want, you should the see the search results below as you type, click the icon to launch.

Comment: Nothing comes up.When I goto software center the green checks are on the games I have.When I click a game I have it comes up with "more info" or "remove". When I open the dash and type the game name nothing comes up.I also went to byobu terminal says "file does not exist.

Comment: I am not familiar with "byobu" but apt-cache search byobu returns byobu - powerful, text based window manager and shell multiplexer.
Using the command 'byobu' in a terminal should launch it, it 'man byobu' will show the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're confusing the Unity Dash with the Ubuntu Software Center. Simultaneously press the "Super-key" (Windows-key) and "A" to bring up the Applications Dash. From there you can type the name of the game in the search field or "Filter Results" just to the right of the Dash Search. You can then use the filter to view all the games you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can look games in directory `/usr/games`. All games will found there.

Comment: Nothing comes up.When I goto software center the green checks are on the games I have.When I click a game I have it comes up with "more info" or "remove". The directory says "file does not exist".