# How do i access previously installed software after update

Tags: upgrade

After upgrade I can't find my games & gnucash.  Software center says they're installed but can't open them from there.

Documents and Downloads are alright.

Comment: may be this can help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/154993/how-are-games-launched/154995#154995